# Is there a PlotLabels placement such as "Above Left" or "Below Right", etc.?

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

I am trying to add labels to a plot in specific positions. I give a simple example:

```
Plot[1 - x^2, {x, -1, 1},
    PlotLabels -> Placed[{"A", "B", "C"},
    {{-1,Left},{0, Above}, {1, Right}}]]
```

So I would like to have the labels A, B, C at the locations x=-1,0,1 of the plot. I know of "Above", "Below", "Left", "Right" as locations for the labels to be placed. However I would like something like "Above Left" or "Above Right", so A and C are not intersecting the x-axis, and B is not intersection the y-axis.

Does that command exist?

Simply choosing the locations Above ±(1+epsilon) does not work, since the plot range is from -1 to 1.

If there is a way to fine-tune the concrete position that would also be nice to know how that works. I actually wouldn't necessarily require labels to a curve, but simply labels at some chosen coordinate in the plot.

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: `Plot[1 - x^2, {x, -1, 1}, PlotLabels -> Placed[{"A"}, {-1, Left}], PlotRange -> All]` works for me as well as simple `Plot[1 - x^2, {x, -1, 1}, PlotLabels -> Placed[{"A"}, {Left}], PlotRange -> All]`.

Comment: @Alx Thanks for the answer! I meanwhile also found out, that I can just enter the location as coordinates, e.g. {{-1.05,1.05},{…},{…}}.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Plot[{1 - x^2,1 - x^2,1 - x^2}, {x, -1, 1},
   PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][1], 
   PlotLabels -> Placed[{"A", "B", "C"},
     {{Left, Bottom}, {Right, Bottom}, {Above,Left}}]]
```

[image]

```
 Plot[{1 - x^2, 1 - x^2, 1 - x^2}, {x, -1, 1},
   PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][1], 
   PlotLabels -> Placed[{"A", "B", "C"},
       {{-1, .1}, {.1, 1}, {1, .1}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot good Sir!

Comment: @Britzel, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.